# Word taxonomies for Facebook likes categories

Tags: nlp

I query the [Facebook graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) to get some users' likes, which come with a "category" field, which can be, for instance, *Italian Restaurant* or *Health & Wellness website* and so on.

I need to draw a profile of the user so I was thinking of retrieving the top level root in a taxonomy graph of the aforementioned categories in such a way that the first example falls into something like *Food* and the second one into something like *Health*. This way I'd know, by a majority rule, who is a sporty person, who likes fashion etc.

Is there a free public API I could use to get word taxonomies? I found [Alchemy](http://www.alchemyapi.com), an IBM project which is pretty cool but unfortunately limited to 1000 API requests per day and I'd need way more than that given the big amount of users and categories I have.

I know I'm probably asking for too much (a free and unlimited tool!) so the question might become "do you have better ideas about how to solve this"?

Answer (score 4):

I think total number of default categories in Facebook is somewhat static. There is around 140-160 categories.

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216648/facebook-pages-authoritative-list-of-categories/8576572#8576572 and http://www.marketinggum.com/types-of-facebook-pages-for-business/

You can cluster (manually) them in to 10-12 generic groups.

eg: Sports Event, 
    Sports League, 
    Amateur sports team,
    Sports Venue,
    Athlete,
    Sports/Recreation/Activities etc
all belongs to Sports category.

Similarly cluster and form generic groups.

And then you can assign a user to any of these generic group based on the like category.

Comment: How would you "cluster" them into more generic groups? By means of a linguistic distance?

Comment: In this case since number of FB categories are less, you can manually cluster them or go for similarity matching algorithms such as BOW/cosine similarity/ wordvec etc

Comment: @Sreejithc321 Your observation about the number of categories simplified the problem greatly.

Comment: By the way, I am finding more than a thousand categories from Facebook.